# CRSF and SSL certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, ssl, model-view-controller

Consider a website with HTTPS protocol.

While using HTTPS, does the protocol use certificate to identify the client?

If some hacker has encrypted cookie after making CSRF, does he need also to have an SSLl certification for further usage?

How can the hacker uses the client data within the website if he has no SSL certification?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question, nor what it has to do with ASP.NET-mvc or the model-view-controller pattern.  HTTPS uses a certificate to encrypt the session, and can in no way identify the client. There is such a thing as a client-certificate authentication, but that requires the certificate be pre-installed on the client.  Further, even client-side certificates do not protect from attacks that originate on the client computer (say a piece of malware running in the background)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

Comment: I know what a CSRF attack is.  That doesn't make your question any clearer, since you obviously did not read the section titled "Ineffective mitigations".  CSRF has nothing to do with HTTPS specifically.  And, again, it has nothing to do with MVC either, it's a general HTTP problem.

Comment: Eric you said the certificate needs to be installed that's true.. how does the hacker get it ? and if he does not get it he gets an encrypted cookie , how can he have farther use of this cookie without having this certification ? this is mostly the question,i faced this problem in ASP.NET MVC so it has to do with it in some way :)

Comment: I said it's *possible* to use client-side certificates.  This is almost never the case in the real world, except for very security conscious situations, because it's very difficult to securely distribute the client certifications.  Thus, it's typically only used in internal environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To launch a CSRF attack, the hacker doesn't need to know the certificate or the cookie. The CSRF attack works because browsers automatically send cookies to the server `example.com`, if **any webpage** contains an `<img src="https://example.com/">` tag.

For example, `example.com` allows users to up vote posts on its forum. Suppose when the user clicks "upvote" button, it sends a request to `https://example.com/vote.php?id=12345`. If the website doesn't use any anti-CSRF techniques, attackers can include a `<img src="https://example.com/vote.php?id=12345>"` tag on his website `https://evil.com`. Then if a user who has logged in to `example.com` later visits `https://evil.com` in the same browser, he would up vote the post without any notice.

I guess you confused between [man-in-the-middle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) (MITM) attacks and CSRF attacks, which are totally different. When you said

> if he does not get it he gets an encrypted cookie , how can he have farther use of this cookie without having this certification ?

you described a MITM attack. MITM attackers intercept the traffic between users and servers. They try to record cookies sent in cleartext, and use the cookies to authenticate themselves. HTTPS already prevents attacks like this. There is no way attackers can decrypt HTTPS traffic.